# cURL - CONNECTION OPTIONS

Tags: php, curl

What happens if both `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` are set?
Same question for `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`.

Is it possible to do that?
If so Which property will be taken into account?

Comment: I'd just set them to very different settings (one set to half a second, one set to five seconds, for example) and see which it uses.

Comment: it'd be like most other curl options - last one specified takes effect. the only diff between the two options is one's in seconds, and one's in milliseconds. internally they're both stored in the same place, and whatever the internal representation is, the other option gets converted to that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> If both CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS are set, the value set
>   last will be used.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.html

The docs don't explicitly mention the same information for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` & `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` but I'd assume the same rule applies. Either way it should be pretty easy to test.